# Как сделать столбец на основе голосований за частый класс

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Требуется сделать столбец  tab4  на основе остальных со следующей логикой: в tab4  попадает самый частый класс, если все классы отличны, то выбрать значение из 1 столбца. Сравнение проводить по каждому элементу в списке, в примере их 2, на деле на сотню.

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'tab1':[[1,2],[2,2],[2,2]],'tab2':[[1,3],[2,3],[1,3]],'tab3':[[1,2],[2,3],[4,3]]})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что в данном случае имеется в виду под классом? Приведите пример выходных данных - что при таких входных данных должно получиться, по описанию не очень понятно. Ну и главное - в чём у вас сложность, где ваши попытки самостоятельно решить задачу?

Answer (score 2):

воспользуйтесь методом `mode`:

```
data1["tab4"] = data1.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0]
                            if len(x.mode())==1
                            else x["tab1"], axis=1)
print(data1)
```

```
     tab1    tab2    tab3    tab4
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]  [2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Всегда считал, что `apply` значительно замедляет расчет в `pandas`. Сделал вариант без `apply` и, что удивительно, проиграл во времени на исходном коротком фрейме в 2 раза! Решил исследовать 4 варианта:

```
#1 - Решение @strawdog:
data1.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if len(x.mode()) == 1 else x["tab1"], axis=1) 
#2 - Решение @strawdog c оптимизацией (y := x.mode()):
data1.apply(lambda x: y[0] if len(y := x.mode()) == 1 else x["tab1"], axis=1)
#3 - Решение с mode, mask и подсчётом NaN:
data1['tab1'].mask((d := data1.mode(axis=1)).isna().sum().eq(0), d[0])
#4 - Решение с apply и value_counts:
data1.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], axis=1)
```

Тестовый код:

```
import time

repeats, mult_row, mult_lists = 100, 1, 1
data = pd.DataFrame({'tab1': [[1, 2] * mult_lists, [2, 2] * mult_lists, [2, 2] * mult_lists], 'tab2': [[1, 3] * mult_lists, [2, 3] * mult_lists, [1, 3] * mult_lists],
                     'tab3': [[1, 2] * mult_lists, [2, 3] * mult_lists, [4, 3] * mult_lists]})
data = data.reindex(list(data.index) * mult_row).reset_index(drop=True)
print(data.head())

print(f'Повторов = {repeats}, множитель количества строк = {mult_row}, множитель количества элементов списков = {mult_lists}')

t = time.time()
for _ in range(repeats):
    data1 = data
    data1["tab4"] = data1.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if len(x.mode()) == 1 else x["tab1"], axis=1)
print('Решение @strawdog:', time.time() - t)

print(data1.head())

t = time.time()
for _ in range(repeats):
    data1 = data
    data1["tab4"] = data1.apply(lambda x: y[0] if len(y := x.mode()) == 1 else x["tab1"], axis=1)
print('Решение @strawdog c оптимизацией (y := x.mode()):', time.time() - t)

print(data1.head())

t = time.time()
for _ in range(repeats):
    data1 = data
    data1['tab4'] = data1['tab1'].mask((d := data1.mode(axis=1)).isna().sum().eq(0), d[0])
print('Решение с mode, mask и подсчётом NaN:', time.time() - t)

print(data1.head())

t = time.time()
for _ in range(repeats):
    data1 = data
    data1["tab4"] = data1.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], axis=1)
print('Решение с apply и value_counts:', time.time() - t)

print(data1.head())
```

```
     tab1    tab2    tab3
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]
Повторов = 100, множитель количества строк = 1, множитель количества элементов списков = 1
Решение @strawdog: 0.07100152969360352
     tab1    tab2    tab3    tab4
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]  [2, 2]
Решение @strawdog c оптимизацией (y := x.mode()): 0.04800248146057129
     tab1    tab2    tab3    tab4
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]  [2, 2]
Решение с mode, mask и подсчётом NaN: 0.14499926567077637
     tab1    tab2    tab3    tab4
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]  [2, 2]
Решение с apply и value_counts: 0.07299947738647461
     tab1    tab2    tab3    tab4
0  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]  [2, 3]
2  [2, 2]  [1, 3]  [4, 3]  [2, 2]
```

Если размножить строки в 100 раз, то решение без `apply` немного выигрывает у решения @strawdog, но все равно проигрывает оптимизированному решению @strawdog. Хотя в решении без `apply` вычисление `mode()` производилось однократно, а у решения с `apply` вычисление `mode()` делалось для каждой строки.
Вывод - решения с `apply` вполне производительные и могут быть более быстрыми, чем другие методы. Нужно замерять.